# Как объединить результаты 2 select в один JSON?

Tags: java, json, jsp

Здравствуйте.

Пробую на JSP реализовать выгрузку результатов 2-х select в один JSON.

```html
                <c:set var="SCRIPT_FailedCount">
    SELECT 1 as MEAS_VALUE, 'First_Table' from dual
    union
    SELECT 2 as MEAS_VALUE, 'First_Table' from dual
    union
    SELECT 3 as MEAS_VALUE, 'First_Table' from dual
    union
    SELECT 4 as MEAS_VALUE, 'First_Table' from dual
                </c:set>
      <c:set var="SCRIPT_SucceededCount">
    SELECT 40 as MEAS_VALUE, 'Second_Table' from dual
    union
    SELECT 30 as MEAS_VALUE, 'Second_Table' from dual
    union
    SELECT 20 as MEAS_VALUE, 'Second_Table' from dual
    union
    SELECT 10 as MEAS_VALUE, 'Second_Table' from dual
    </c:set>  

            <sql:query var="SCRIPT_FailedCount" dataSource="jdbc/Oracle">
                ${SCRIPT_FailedCount}
            </sql:query>

              <sql:query var="SCRIPT_SucceededCount" dataSource="jdbc/Oracle">
                ${SCRIPT_SucceededCount}
            </sql:query>
      
              <%@ taglib prefix="json" uri="http://www.atg.com/taglibs/json" %>
            <c:set var="json_text" scope="application">
            <json:object>
            <json:array name="FailedCount" prettyPrint="false">
            <c:forEach var="row" items="${SCRIPT_FailedCount.rows}">
            <json:object>
                <json:property name="FailedCount_MEAS_VALUE" value="${row.MEAS_VALUE}"/>
            </json:object>
            </c:forEach>
            </json:array>

            <json:array name="SucceededCount" prettyPrint="false">
            <c:forEach var="row" items="${SCRIPT_SucceededCount.rows}">
            <json:object>
                <json:property name="SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE" value="${row.MEAS_VALUE}"/>
            </json:object>
            </c:forEach>
            </json:array>
            </json:object>
        </c:set>
```

в результате получается вот такой JSON

```html
{
"FailedCount":[{"FailedCount_MEAS_VALUE":1},
{"FailedCount_MEAS_VALUE":2},
{"FailedCount_MEAS_VALUE":3},
{"FailedCount_MEAS_VALUE":4}],
"SucceededCount":[{"SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE":10},
{"SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE":20},
{"SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE":30},
{"SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE":40}]
}
```

Подскажите, как на JSP, объединить 2 результата select, чтобы получился общий JSON такого вида:

```html
{
"Failed_Succeeded_Count":[
{"FailedCount_MEAS_VALUE":1,"SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE":10},
{"FailedCount_MEAS_VALUE":2, "SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE":20},
{"FailedCount_MEAS_VALUE":3, "SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE":30},
{"FailedCount_MEAS_VALUE":4, "SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE":40}]
}
```

Comment: Есть ли связь между записями FailedCount_MEAS_VALUE":1 и "SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE":10? Т.е. как связаны между собой таблицы(первая и вторая)? По времени? По каким-то полям?

Comment: Количество записей FailedCount_MEAS_VALUE и SucceededCount_MEAS_VALUE будет одинаковым, по времени они также будут совпадать